# How to count a map loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make bolder the first loop of my table and the rest of them will be normal size. I want to count the `map` loop and check if it is `1`, I will make `style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}` in `<td>` tag.
How can I do that?

**mycode**

```
<table>
  ...
  {categories.map((val) => (
    <tr>
      <td>{val.name}</td>
      <td>{val.formula}</td>
      <td>{val.values[0].value.toLocaleString()}</td>
      <td>{val.values[1].value.toLocaleString()}</td>
      <td>{val.description}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

Comment: Use `map`’s callback function’s `index` parameter? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: You can use the second parameter to the `map`'s callback function `index`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to map function is the index, you can use that to check the condition.

```
{categories.map( (val, index) => {
    if(index == 0)
       return ....
    else return ....
  }
)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in css.

```
tr:first-child {
      fontWeight:'bold';
    }
```

Comment: In the long run this is a more-robust answer than my comment suggestion. I always think code-first :/